# I am using RuleFit for binary classification; how do I interpret the rules?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am using RuleFit with a GradientBoostingClassifier to generate rules for a binary classification problem (health-dataset on Kaggle).  When I print out the rules with RuleFit.get_rules(), it shows rule, type, coef, support, and importance.  But it doesn’t show which class (0 or 1) is the target of the rule.  For example: does exang <= 0.5 describe a 0 or 1 class?

Summary: how do I know which target class a given rule is describing?

Answer (score 0):

"RuleFit learns a sparse linear model with the original features and also a number of new features that are decision rules. These new features capture interactions between the original features. RuleFit automatically generates these features from decision trees. Each path through a tree can be transformed into a decision rule by combining the split decisions into a rule." ([reference](https://christophm.github.io/interpretable-ml-book/rulefit.html))

Also, from this [example](https://hacarus.com/ai-lab/20211208-rulefit/) we understand that rf.get_rules() will return the rules created from initial attributes and created attributes, but not the predictions.

I am therefore assuming the prediction results come from your GradientBoostingClassifier's [predict](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifier.predict) method. If that is the case, then the most natural thing to do is to indeed select a threshold above which you consider if a sample is predicted as a 0 or 1. Here is a possible example:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.3,random_state=42)
reg = GradientBoostingClassifier()
reg.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = reg.predict(X_test)
thresh = 0.5
y_pred = np.array([y_pred > thresh])
```

Notice that the threshold may not be 0.5, depending on what you are aiming for.
For more about this, I encourage you to look for the [Area Under the Curve](https://medium.com/@sarath13/area-under-the-roc-curve-explained-d056854d3815) metric.

I hope this helped!